# Error in play framework while testing integrationTest.java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, integration-testing

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Map
  at IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:20)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Map
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  ... 24 more
```

i am using play framework in java. i need to implement phantomJS. so i try to run        IntegrationTest.java but i got an error. And how could i change the default browser to firefox
of selenium. 
import org.junit.*;

```
  import play.mvc.*;
  import play.test.*;
  import play.libs.F.*;

  import static play.test.Helpers.*;
  import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;

  import static org.fluentlenium.core.filter.FilterConstructor.*;

  public class IntegrationTest {

/**
 * add your integration test here
 * in this example we just check if the welcome page is being shown
 */
  @Test
  public void test() {
  running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, new     Callback<TestBrowser>() {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
            assertThat(browser.pageSource()).contains("Your new application is ready.");
        }
    });
}

}
```

This is IntegrationTEst.java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `scala-library.jar` is missing in your classpath. Download and add it to the classpath.

You also need the `scala-parser-combinators.jar`

Comment: By using [`sbt`](http://www.scala-sbt.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or any other dependency/build management tool you can manage your dependencies, your test dependencies, etc. and change them easily over time.